# How add my geolocation as origin in angular2

Tags: ionic2, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

the code is  found ok, only need help to add my geolocation as origin, some one can helpme ?[the base of my code](https://r.redirekted.com/redirect?redirect_id=15f3d64ab087674848e355de044dfa74&request_id=3a2a70bb6e06c71dfdb3d1eaca6c18c4)

this is my component.ts or my contact.ts from ionic2

```
import { Component, NgModule,NgZone,OnInit,ViewChild,ElementRef,Directive,Input } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule}from'@angular/forms';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Geolocation} from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { DirectionsMapDirective} from '../../mapD/DirectionsMap.directive';
import {AgmCoreModule,MapsAPILoader, GoogleMapsAPIWrapper}  from '@agm/core';
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';


declare var google: any;
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html',
  providers:[GoogleMapsAPIWrapper]
})
export class ContactPage implements OnInit{
  
  public latitude: number;
  public longitude: number;
  public destinationInput: FormControl;
  public destinationOutput: FormControl;
  public zoom: number;
  public iconurl: string;
  public mapCustomStyles : any;
  public estimatedTime: any;
  public estimatedDistance: any;

  @ViewChild("pickupInput")
  public pickupInputElementRef: ElementRef;

   @ViewChild("pickupOutput")
  public pickupOutputElementRef: ElementRef;

   @ViewChild("scrollMe")
  private scrollContainer: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild(DirectionsMapDirective) vc: DirectionsMapDirective;

  public origin :any ; // its a example aleatory position
  public destination : any; // its a example aleatory position
  constructor(
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private gmapsApi: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper,
    private _elementRef : ElementRef
  ) {
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    //set google maps defaults
    this.zoom = 4;
    this.latitude = 39.8282;
    this.longitude = -98.5795;
    //this.iconurl = '../image/map-icon.png';
    this.iconurl = '../image/map-icon.png';

   // this.mapCustomStyles = this.getMapCusotmStyles();
    //create search FormControl
    this.destinationInput = new FormControl();
    this.destinationOutput = new FormControl();
    console.log(this.destinationInput)
    console.log(this.destinationOutput)
    //set current position
    this.setCurrentPosition();
    
    //load Places Autocomplete
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
        let autocompleteInput = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.pickupInputElementRef.nativeElement, {
          types: ["address"]
        });

        let autocompleteOutput = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.pickupOutputElementRef.nativeElement, {
          types: ["address"]
        });
      
               this.setupPlaceChangedListener(autocompleteInput, 'ORG');
              this.setupPlaceChangedListener(autocompleteOutput, 'DES');
    });
  }
  
  private setupPlaceChangedListener(autocomplete: any, mode: any ) {
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            
            //get the place result
            let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
            //verify result
            if (place.geometry === undefined) {
              return;
            }
            if (mode === 'ORG') {
                this.vc.origin = { longitude: place.geometry.location.lng(), latitude: place.geometry.location.lat() }; 
                this.vc.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
                
            } else {
                this.vc.destination = { longitude: place.geometry.location.lng(), latitude: place.geometry.location.lat() }; // its a example aleatory position
                this.vc.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
            }

            if(this.vc.directionsDisplay === undefined){ this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => { 
                  this.vc.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
                }); 
          }
          console.log(this.vc.originPlaceId);
            //Update the directions
            this.vc.updateDirections();
            this.zoom = 12;
          });

       });

  }

  getDistanceAndDuration(){
    this.estimatedTime = this.vc.estimatedTime;
    this.estimatedDistance = this.vc.estimatedDistance;
  }

  scrollToBottom(): void {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery(document).height() }, 3000);
  }
  private setPickUpLocation( place:any ) {
    //verify result
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }
          //set latitude, longitude and zoom
          this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
          this.zoom = 40;
  }

  private setCurrentPosition() {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        this.zoom = 12;
      });
    }
  }

  private getMapCusotmStyles() {
    // Write your Google Map Custom Style Code Here.
  }

}
```

this is the directive in ionic 2

```
  import { Directive, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper} from'@agm/core';

declare var google: any;
@Directive({selector:'agm-map-directions'})
export class DirectionsMapDirective{
  @Input() origin:any ;
  @Input() destination:any;
  @Input() originPlaceId:any;
  @Input() destinationPlaceId:any;
  @Input() waypoints:any;
  @Input() directionsDisplay:any;
  @Input() estimatedTime : any;
  @Input() estimatedDistance : any;
 
  constructor (private gmapsApi: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper) {}
  updateDirections(){
    this.gmapsApi.getNativeMap().then(map => {
              if(!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId 
              ){
                return;
              
              }
              console.log(this.originPlaceId);
              
              var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
              var me = this;
              var latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: this.origin.latitude, lng: this.origin.longitude });
              var latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: this.destination.latitude, lng: this.destination.longitude });
              
              this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
              this.directionsDisplay.setOptions({
                polylineOptions: {
                            strokeWeight: 8,
                            strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                            strokeColor:  '#00468c' 
                        }
                });
              this.directionsDisplay.setDirections({routes: []});
              directionsService.route({
                      origin: {placeId : this.originPlaceId },
                      destination: {placeId : this.destinationPlaceId },
                      avoidHighways: true,
                      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                      
                      //travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                    }, function(response: any, status: any) {
                                if (status === 'OK') {
                                  me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                                  map.setZoom(30);
                                  //console.log(me.getcomputeDistance (latLngA, latLngB));
                                  var point = response.routes[ 0 ].legs[ 0 ];
                                  me.estimatedTime = point.duration.text ;
                                  me.estimatedDistance = point.distance.text;
                                  console.log(me.estimatedTime);
                                  console.log( 'Estimated travel time: ' + point.duration.text + ' (' + point.distance.text + ')' );
 
                                } else {
                                  console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                                }
              });
    });

  }

  private getcomputeDistance(latLngA: any , latLngB: any ) 
  {
    return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLngA, latLngB) / 1000).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

this is html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      mapa
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [scrollwheel]="false"
  [zoom]="zoom" [styles]="mapCustomStyles">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [iconUrl]="iconurl">
    <agm-info-window>
      <strong>InfoWindow content</strong>
    </agm-info-window>
  </agm-marker>
  <agm-map-directions [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination"></agm-map-directions>
</agm-map>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
  <input placeholder="Enter source location" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off"
  type="text" class="form-control" #pickupInput [formControl]="destinationInput">
  
  <input placeholder="Enter destination" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off"
  type="text" class="form-control" #pickupOutput [formControl]="destinationOutput">
</div>
</ion-content>
```

my code is from http://www.17educations.com/angularjs-2/google-map-directions-display-angular-2/